# order by and project distinct objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by, projection

I have data something like this:

```
 Id  |  Customer  |  CartTotal
-------------------------------
 1   |      a     |     100 
 2   |      a     |     50
 3   |      b     |     110
 4   |      b     |     128
```

I need to order it by `CartTotal` (descending) and return distinct customers
so that I should have this in my result set:

```
 Id  |  Customer  |  CartTotal
-------------------------------
  4  |      b     |     128
  1  |      a     |     100
```

I believe I need to do an order and projection. I'm working with a strongly typed `IList<>` datasource. I'm new to LINQ.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what criteria you use to choose a value of 128 for CartTotal for `b` and a value of 100 for CartTotal for `a`.  Each has two separate values defined, which should be used?

Comment: @KirkWoll If I were to guess, I'd say use `max` :)

Comment: Why do you pick Ids 1 and 4 rather than 2 and 3 ? Are you looking for the rows with the max CartTotal value ?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with ".net Linq: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Yes, I need the max carttotal value for each customer @ThomasLevesque

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should do what you're after:

```
var filteredPurchases = purchases.OrderByDescending(p => p.CartTotal)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Customer)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

It will return the purchase with the maximum `CartTotal` for each `Customer`, giving the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The answers so far, while correct, are significantly less efficient then needed because they 1)sort before grouping and 2)only need the largest element in the first place.  Sorting first makes the solution `O(n*log(n))`.

Taking care of number 1, we can do the following:

```
var query = purchases
    .GroupBy(p => p.Customer)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.CartTotal).First());
```

This gets us a solution something like `O(n + n * log(n/c)`, where c is the number of customers. Assuming that orders per customer is roughly constant, it is `O(n)`.

Now, we can do better, by just finding the maximum element for each customer and selecting it in one pass. Unfortunately, the Max operator in Linq makes this more painful than it should be. If you pull down [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), you can do the following:

```
var query = purchases
    .GroupBy(p => p.Customer)
    .Select(g => g.MaxBy(p => p.CartTotal));
```

This solution is always `O(n)`, regardless of the distribution of purchases to customers. I would also expect it to be the fastest by far on large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query expression version:

```
var query = from cart in carts
            orderby cart.CartTotal descending
            group cart by cart.Customer into custCarts
            select custCarts.First();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the query expression syntax also @AndrewCooper